# How to focus editor after clicking file in the VS Code Explorer View?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When selecting a file via click in the Explorer View, it opens, but the focus stays in the Explorer View (in older versions focus would move to the spawned editor).

I get that a key can be bound to move focus to the file's editor, but I'd prefer focus to instead move there.

Otherwise, I select a file, hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to go somewhere in it, but of course the find widget opens up for the files explorer instead.

Comment: double click the file, or use `Ctrl+1` or `Ctrl+2` depending on which tab group has the focus

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but the goal as I mentioned is not to have to press keys when an item is clicked

Comment: For completeness, you can also just hit `Enter` after clicking to open a file from the Explorer and that will pass focus.  I know you don't want to hit more keys to pass focus...

Comment: I just found out there is an extension for this, search for: "Focus file on click" from Steven Rafferty. Thanks Steven!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get focus to go to the editor from the explorer by double-clicking in the explorer view. ([related issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84527)).

There's a feature-request to make it so the editor will be focused just by a single click: [Setting to focus editor on mouse click #166118](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166118). <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

Note that if you're using the *keyboard* and not the mouse, pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> should automatically move focus to the opened editor. You can also look into the `explorer.openAndPassFocus` and `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus` keyboard shortcut binding commands.